# problem changing the date format of a datepicker in angular

Tags: angular, datetime

I have a problem in capturing a date with the datapicker component which by default takes dd-mm-yyyy but I just need to take the mm-yyyy format

What could I do?
thanks for your kind help

Comment: Pls post your code and which datepicker you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a date pipe in angular for your solution if you are supposed to output this in html.

use something like this:

The time is {{today | date:'MM/yyyy'}}

here is the link with more examples with details: 
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe